# Retrieve first name and secondo name from list of mail

Tags: javascript

Good morning,

I'm looking for a solution to get first name and second name from a list of mail ,separated by " ; "  
Like this example :

```
marco.marco@email.it;andrea.andrea@email.it;paolo.paolo@email.it;wally.wally@email.it
```

how to get back this answer : 
 
- marco marco 
- andrea andrea 
- paolo paolo

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `split()` method. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Eg:

```js
var list = 'marco.marco@email.it;andrea.andrea@email.it;paolo.paolo@email.it;wally.wally@email.it';
var items = list.split(';');
var result = [];
items.forEach(function(i){
let names = i.substring(0, i.indexOf('@')).split('.');
result.push(names[0]+' '+names[1]);
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can split on the delimiter: ;
i.e.

```
const mailers = mailerList.split(";");
```

Then, you could use the first index of the split from the @ to extract the usernames:

```
const mailers = mailerList.split(";");
let usernames = [];
mailers.forEach(currMailer=>{
    usernames = mailers.split("@")[0];
}
```

Lastly, once you have those usernames, you can extract the first/last name with delimiter '.' to get arrays of size 2 with first name in the first index and last name in the second index.

```
let mailers = mailerList.split(";");
let usernames = [];
mailers.forEach(currMailer=>{
    usernames = mailers.split("@")[0];
}
let userCombos = [];
usernames.forEach(currUser=>{
    const splitName = currUser.split(".");
    userCombos.push({firstName: splitName[0], secondName: splitName[1]});
}
```